# Is is possible to port forward without access to the router page in linux?

Tags: networking, command-line, router, port-forwarding, raspbian

I want to port forward a server on my raspberry pi running raspbian headless. I don't know the password to my router settings and don't want to go through the effort of resetting all of the settings to be able to access it. Is there a way that I can set up port forwarding through the command line in Linux?

Comment: Probably not. Every router I've ever used that had Telnet or SSH shell access used the same username/password that the configuration web application uses. some of the fancier ones may have a console connection you could jack into, but in anything modern, you can expect it to have some kind of authentication requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If the Router and Operating System both Support UPNP,
**The Simple answer is yes.**

Some ISP routers, Like Verizon Actiontecs "Mi424wr" here in the US. do not even allow you to disable it.

I believe UPNP support must be enabled in the Host Operating system. But when enabled on both it will automatically create port forwards for the program requesting it.

MiniUPnP is a command line UPnP client that allows you to enable port forwarding.

I think you could compile it on a pi, probably from the source code.

Comment: UPNP must be supported by the Application itself, not just the host. the host has no idea that a port needs forwarded.

Comment: @frank Thomas, you are correct, that's where MiniUpNP comes into this situation. It's also why I put "automatically create port forwards for the PROGRAM requesting it." do you feel this needs to be elaborated?

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to port forward from any device behind the Router for inbound connections. You will need to do it from the Router.